# AEM: getting current locale from $PATH

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I am reading values for dropdown using selector + request parameters.

```
/bin/services/myservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.json?locale=$PATH
```

the `$PATH` gives me `currentPath.path`. I can I get the current locale using the path.

for example:

```
/bin/services/myservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.json?locale=en-us
```

How can I return only the locale from the $PATH and pass it to locale. That will resolve the issue.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Though a few remarks: a "SlingServlet" with a path can't use selectors. Use "resourceTypes" and then you already have the path to your current page and can read out the language from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(path);
if (resource != null) {
    Page targetPage = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);
    if (targetPage != null) {
        Locale pageLocale = targetPage.getLanguage(true);
        String countryLocale = pageLocale.getCountry();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve locale using $PATH

```
/bin/services/myservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.json?locale=$PATH


String compNodePath = (String) request.getParameter("locale");  
String pagePath = StringUtils.substringBefore(compNodePath, "jcr:content");  
PageManager pageMgr = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(PageManager.class);  
Page page = pageMgr.getContainingPage(pagePath);  
Locale pageLocale = page.getLanguage(false);
```

For this to work, Language field in page properties should be set to a suitable value.